# How to prevent selected index from changing when bound data changes?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Using knockout, I have a select (a list of names) whose options are bound to another set of knockout-bound data (people). When the name of any person changes, the value of the select option that is bound to that person's name is correctly updated. However, the select's selection is not preserved if you had that person selected already.

See this jsFiddle for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/DbBZQ/

1. Select "Jane" from the list.
2. Change the name "Jane" to something else ("Jane Doe" for example).
3. Notice the select defaults back to the first item.

How can I make the selection stick to the same option index even if the underlying value has changed? Is there a way to instruct knockout to preserve the selection or do I have to do this separately using JS?

**Complete Code Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data =
            {
                people: ko.observableArray(
                [
                    { name: ko.observable("Jim") },
                    { name: ko.observable("Jane") },
                    {
                        name: ko.observable("Sam"),
                        subordinates: ko.observableArray(
                        [
                            { 
                        name: ko.observable("Tambone"),
                                subordinates: ko.observableArray(
                                [
                                    { name: ko.observable("Edward") },
                                    { name: ko.observable("Kristy") },
                                    { name: ko.observable("Thomas") },
                                    { name: ko.observable("Andy") }
                                ])
                            },
                            { name: ko.observable("Jules") }
                        ])
                    }
                ])
            };
            var allNames = ko.computed(function ()
            {
                var names = [];
                var selector = function (name, indent)
                {
                    var option =
                    {
                        value: name,
                        text: (indent || "") + name
                    };

                    return option;
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < data.people().length; i++)
                {
                    names.push(selector(data.people()[i].name()));
                    addSubordinates(names, 1, data.people()[i].subordinates, selector);
                }

                return names;
            });

            function addSubordinates(names, depth, subordinates, selector)
            {
                if (subordinates != null)
                {
                    var indentText = "";

                    for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
                        indentText += ". . ";

                    for (var i = 0; i < subordinates().length; i++)
                    {
                        names.push(selector(subordinates()[i].name(), indentText));
                        addSubordinates(names, depth + 1, subordinates()[i].subordinates, selector);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-bind="foreach: data.people">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" /><br />
        </div>
        <a href="JavaScript:data.people.push({ name: ko.observable('New Person') });">Add Person</a>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <select data-bind="options: allNames, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: 'All Names...'" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            ko.applyBindings();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the selection is lost is because the selected value is matched directly to the name property, which changes.  As a result, the selected value no longer exists in the data source (allNames).

If you want to retain the selection, you have a couple of options:

1. Implement a hack such as tracking the index, and resetting it after the value changes
2. Bind the selected value to a property that doesn't change.

Do you have an immutable property that you can use as the selected value?

For the sake of an example, I added an id property to the objects in the data source, and use that as the selected value instead of name.  This works the way you expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data =
            {
                people: ko.observableArray(
                [
                    { id: 1, name: ko.observable("Jim") },
                    { id: 2, name: ko.observable("Jane") },
                    {
                        id: 3, name: ko.observable("Sam"),
                        subordinates: ko.observableArray(
                        [
                            { 
                        id: 4, name: ko.observable("Tambone"),
                                subordinates: ko.observableArray(
                                [
                                    { id: 5, name: ko.observable("Edward") },
                                    { id: 6, name: ko.observable("Kristy") },
                                    { id: 7, name: ko.observable("Thomas") },
                                    { id: 8, name: ko.observable("Andy") }
                                ])
                            },
                            { id: 9, name: ko.observable("Jules") }
                        ])
                    }
                ])
            };
            var allNames = ko.computed(function ()
            {
                var names = [];
                var selector = function (id, name, indent)
                {
                    var option =
                    {
                        value: id,
                        text: (indent || "") + name
                    };

                    return option;
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < data.people().length; i++)
                {
                    names.push(selector(data.people()[i].id, data.people()[i].name()));
                    addSubordinates(names, 1, data.people()[i].subordinates, selector);
                }

                return names;
            });

            function addSubordinates(names, depth, subordinates, selector)
            {
                if (subordinates != null)
                {
                    var indentText = "";

                    for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
                        indentText += ". . ";

                    for (var i = 0; i < subordinates().length; i++)
                    {
                        names.push(selector(subordinates()[i].id,subordinates()[i].name(), indentText));
                        addSubordinates(names, depth + 1, subordinates()[i].subordinates, selector);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-bind="foreach: data.people">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" /><br />
        </div>
        <a href="JavaScript:data.people.push({ name: ko.observable('New Person') });">Add Person</a>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <select data-bind="options: allNames, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: 'All Names...'" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            ko.applyBindings();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
As an alternative, what if you set up the `value` property so that it was a ko.computed that returned the index of the item?  Like this:

```
var allNames = ko.computed(function ()
{
    var names = [];
    var selector = function (item, name, indent)
    {
        var option =
        {
            value: ko.computed(function(){ return data.people().indexOf(item);}),
            text: (indent || "") + name
        };

        return option;
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < data.people().length; i++)
    {
        names.push(selector(data.people()[i], data.people()[i].name()));
        addSubordinates(names, 1, data.people()[i].subordinates, selector);
    }

    return names;
});

function addSubordinates(names, depth, subordinates, selector)
{
    if (subordinates != null)
    {
        var indentText = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
            indentText += ". . ";

        for (var i = 0; i < subordinates().length; i++)
        {
            names.push(selector(subordinates()[i],subordinates()[i].name(), indentText));
            addSubordinates(names, depth + 1, subordinates()[i].subordinates, selector);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for a simple binding property like `persistelectedIndex`; but binding to an arbitrary ID would likely work okay. Some of the "thing" I want in my list do have IDs but others don't (e.g. new things added which haven't yet been committed to the DB).

Comment: Well, that's an idea.  What if the 'value' was a computed that returned the index for the item?  I edited the answer to explain this.

Comment: I could also just set the value to `$index` (perhaps, haven't tried).